# View: Link to content is always rendering in the default language

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I have a View that is list of a content type using fields. (I am also using a Relationship and a Contextual Filter, btw.)

One of those fields is "link to content".

The content type is translatable. The View is filtered by `Translation language (= Interface text language selected for page)`. In my secondary language (German) only nodes with a translation are shown. So far, so good.

The rendering language is set to: `Interface text language selected for page`.

However, the rendered rows always link to the default language (`/en`), even when the rest of the page is rendered in the secondary language (`de`).

What can I do to get the rows to render the links in the correct language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug and it's being worked on, the solution is provided and it's currently labeled as `Needs review`. Perhaps you can apply the patch and test yourself:

[Entity Links fields does not have translation support](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2877994)

In Drupal 8.4 and earlier versions it was possible to use the workaround of `Path` field and using Custom text field to construct the link:

`<a href="{{ path }}">{% trans %} View more {% endtrans %}</a>`

The Path field output correctly translated links with correct path prefix, see here: [Translate Content: Link to Content field on Views in Drupal 8](http://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/translate-content-link-content-field-views-drupal-8). But in Drupal 8.5 the Path field is no longer supported, so you have to patch or wait for the update to gets released.

Answer (score 2):

Add 2 fields to your view:

1. a "Content: Node ID (Node ID)" field
2. a "Content: Translation language (Translation language)" field.

Exclude the "Content: Node ID" field from display.

---

Override the output of this field with custom text:

```
{% trans %} View more {% endtrans %}
```

Rewrite the "Content: Translation Language" field as a custom link:

```
{{ langcode_value }}/node/{{ nid }}
```

---

Then go to admin/config/regional/translate.

You may translate View more in any desired language: FILTER TRANSLATABLE STRINGS (View more) and translate it according to language

Answer (score 0):

The Answer by Jturpin helped me fix this issue.
In addition to that you could shorten

```
{% trans %} View more {% endtrans %}
```

to

```
{{'View more'|t}}
```